# Remove App badge with a silent push notification?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I can see in the documentation that there are ways to clear the badge by sending a push notification, but is there a way to clear it without an actual alert appearing? I'm thinking of building a chat client, that can check with the server if the message has been received somewhere else. Check is not the right word though, the server should push down to the iPhone if the message got picked up somewhere else, and clear the badge, but it doesn't need an alert or a sound, just a removal of the badge. Can you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the alert is entirely optional. As ever, [the apple documentation tells all](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9). Set it to zero to clear.

Comment: I've always wondered why some applications don't clear their badges automatically.

Comment: Imagine you have 10,000,000 users. Now imagine the resource requirements of sending them all a message simply to clear down the badge. That could be one reason ...

Comment: 10 million users. I will be happy when my app has that!